# Ajax CascadingDropDown webservice call not working in Custom pages in Dynamic Data website

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have created a Dynamic Data website using the Dynamic Data Website template in ASP.NET 3.5 VS2008. I wanted to have to custom page for a particular table. So I have created a  folder under CustomPages and have created the Details page under it. The details page uses a DetailsView which has few DropDownList which is tied to CascadingDropDown(CDD). The CDDs are using page script methods for servicemethod call.

If I directly access this custom page url path(for debug purpose, I have removed the filter from web.config which prevents this), the webservice call works fine and dropdown list is populated properly. But if I add routing to global.aspx for this specific table and then land on this page, the webservice call is not happening. I am getting the method 404 error. The webservice is within the same website and I have also added the service reference to the project.

So I am unable to figure out, why the servicemethod call fails when it comes through routing and works fine if I access the CustomPage directly?

If anyone has faced similar problem, please let me know how to resolve it.

I am using VS2008, .Net3.5, AjaxControlToolkit 3.5.

Thanks
askids

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. Since I was calling the page method for the web service, the call was failing as that particular path did not exist (it was dynamically routed). I was able to figure this out after installing Fiddler. So I replaced the service method to the actual web service and added the servicepath as well. This resolved the issue!

Thanks

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out the problem for me. I had the same problem with dynamically routed pages.